# Unintended change of value types when debugging

Tags: debugging, decimal

Following problem: I defined a simple unit test which performs some basic calculations with three decimal input parameters. When I step into method GetFxHedgeRelativeInPercentage I observe a parameter change of parameter xauForwardValuta as soon as I step over the first calculation step (see screenshots below).

Why is this happening? Parameter xauForwardValuta is an (immutable) value type and should not change as it is never reassigned. Any ideas?

Environment: VS2017 (15.8.2), .Net Framework 4.7, xUnit 2.4

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    decimal fxHedgeAbsolute = -0.0107612378106512251880194424m;
    decimal totalForwardValue = -100170000.000000000000000m;
    decimal xauForwardValuta = 2202777.418898231m;

    var fxHedgeRelativeInPercentage = GetFxHedgeRelativeInPercentage(fxHedgeAbsolute, totalForwardValue, xauForwardValuta);


    this.testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"{fxHedgeRelativeInPercentage}");

    // -0.0000000105118158185915135200
}
```

**Debug step 1:**
[image: Debug step 1]

**Watch after step 1:**
[image: Watch after step 1]

**Debug step 2:**
[image: Debug step 2]

**Watch after step 2:**
[image: Watch after step 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to debugging in the world of optimization.  This is an artifact of how the compiler implemented your code, and should not be a real problem. (unless you are getting the wrong answer)

As you point out, `xauForwardValuta` is never reassigned, or even used again after the first line.  So the compiler sees that the register it is stored in can be reused.  And it does re-use it for the intermediate calculation of `xauForwardValuta * -1`.

If you debug optimized code, you will often see values change or even disappear as the only register that was holding them gets reused for something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can I - for demo purposes - turn off these compiler optimizations? Under project settings > Build > “Optimize code” option is already unchecked.

Comment: That is a good question, and one I don't know the answer to.  I assume you are already building in "Debug" mode.